# How to decorate console logger messages in Python?

Tags: python, logging, python-3.x, colors, console

I am using a logger in Python, and I want it to show some messages (not all) with colors in console.

Now I do this:

```
print('\033[0;41;97m')
logger.info('Colored message')
print('\033[0m')
```

It works well, but the problem is that there are blank lines above and below the message. I can't do this:

```
print('\033[0;41;97m', end='')
logger.info('Colored message')
print('\033[0m')
```

Because this way there is a blank line below the message. And I can't do this neither:

```
logger.info('\033[0;41;97m' + 'Colored message' + '\033[0m')
```

Because then, when I open the log file I see weird symbols. Any solution, please?

**EDIT**

```
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
fh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_file, 'a', max_bytes, 10)

ch_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-4s - '
                                 '%(message)s',
                                 datefmt='%Y.%m.%d_%H:%M:%S_%Z')
fh_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-4s - '
                                 '%(message)s',
                                 datefmt='%Y.%m.%d_%H:%M:%S_%Z')
ch.setFormatter(ch_formatter)
fh.setFormatter(fh_formatter)

logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

OP says **I am using a RotatingFileHandler**. :)

Define a new `FileHandler` which escapes `ansi color`

```
# file handler for **ansi_escape**
class MyFileHandler(logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler):
    import re
    ansi_escape = re.compile(r'\x1b[^m]*m')
    def emit(self, record):
        record.msg = self.ansi_escape.sub('', record.msg)
        logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler.emit(self, record)
```

Then add this and `StreamHandler` to `logger`

```
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
fh = MyFileHandler('file.log')

ch_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-4s - '
                                 '%(message)s',
                                 datefmt='%Y.%m.%d_%H:%M:%S_%Z')
fh_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-4s - '
                                 '%(message)s',
                                 datefmt='%Y.%m.%d_%H:%M:%S_%Z')


ch.setFormatter(ch_formatter)
fh.setFormatter(fh_formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

Define `infoc`... see below:

```
logger.infoc = lambda msg: logger.info('\033[0;41;97m' + msg + '\033[0m')
```

Finally you can archive...

```
# for colored console but not file
logger.infoc('Colored message')
# for normal
logger.info('Normal message')
```

---

**EDIT**

How about using `wrapper` for the **colored messages**.

```
logger.infoc = lambda msg: logger.info('\033[0;41;97m' + msg + '\033[0m')
logger.infoc('Colored message')
```

---

Use `basicConfig` as

```
fmt = '\033[0;41;97m %(message)s \033[0m'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=fmt)
logger = logging.getLogger(__file__)
logger.info('hello')
```

Or

```
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt))
logger.addHandler(console)

logger.error('hello')
```

**UPDATE**

The **color code** should be in `StreamHandler` only.
Modify `FileHandler` like this:

```
fileh = logging.FileHandler('file.log')
fileh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s')) # remove the color code.
logger.addHandler(fileh)
```

No more weird symbols in your logfile.

Comment: But what if I only want to color some messages, not all of them?

Comment: How's the message determined? decorated or not.

Comment: I simplified the question to make it easier to read, but actually I need to show some messages with very different colors and effects. If I specify format=fmt, every message will be shown with colors but always the same ones, won't it?

Comment: I get what you are doing, it is a good idea, because this way there are not weird symbols in my log file as you say. But the problem is the console formatter will be always the same (same background, text colors for every console message). I need only to apply colors in a few messages.

Comment: No, with the logger.infoc function, color codes will be inside the message and weird symbols will appear in the log file!

Comment: Yes, the color code is also `written` in **file** because the color code is included in **message**. please update your `logger` code. How was it `defined` and `initialized`.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not write that I am using a RotatingFileHandler, not a FileHander. I have edited my code. Now I am trying to adapt your code to mine, but I am not able.

Comment: UPDATED! That's OK :). I am happy I can help you!

Comment: Great! That solution works!! Thank you very much for your friendliness  and your patience!!